# Im calling my dialog when I click in my link but dialog is not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Im deleting images from a gallery by clicking on image using jQuery and ajax.

And it is working fine, but now Im trying to do a message, like an alert asking if user have sure that really want to delete my image.

I know that I can use dialog form jquery user interface that have ok and cancel methods for this, but Im trying to use my own dialog for this.

But when I click in my image in my delete link my dialog is not appearing.

Do you see where can be my error?

My dialog that I want to show when I click in my delete link is this:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="delete">
        <p>Do you really want to delete this image?</p>
        <a href="#">Yes</a>
        <a href="#">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have in my html my delete link like:

```
<div class="galery"> 
  echo '<ul>';
  while ($result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<li id="'.$result['id'].'">';
    echo '<img src="'.$result['img'].'" />';
    echo '<a href="#" id="'.$resul['id'].'" class="galerydel">Delete</a>';
    echo '</li>';
      }
  echo '</ul>';
</div>
```

Then I have my script to show my dialog when I click in my delete:

```
$(function(){
  $('.galery ul').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
  $('.dialog .delete').fadeOut("slow");
   return false;
  });
});
```

Than I have my php, that gets my image id: $imageId = $_POST['image']; and then  I will delete from my table gallery where id is icual to my $imageId.

Comment: Do you want dialog to appear on click? Or disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet,

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub4M9/)

```
$(function(){

  $('.galery').on('click','.galerydel',function(){
      $( ".dialog" ).dialog();
      return false;      //A better way is to use event.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

- You need to set `.dialog` to `display:none` initially.
- `fadeOut()` is used to hide. You have to show the dialog on Click of Delete.

Comment: or more standard: `function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Right @mplungjan, It was just a modification of OP's code. Should have suggested it before though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.galery ul').on('click', '.galerydel', function () { ...}
```

should be

```
$('.galerydel').on('click', function () { ...}
```